# How does the linked list get updated?

Tags: python

This function is for merging two sorted LinkedList:

```
def merge(l1, l2):
    head = sort_list = Node(0)
    while l1 and l2:
        if l1.value < l2.value:
            sort_list.next = l1
            l1 = l1.next
            sort_list = sort_list.next
        elif l1.value >= l2.value:
            sort_list.next = l2
            l2 = l2.next
            sort_list = sort_list.next

    sort_list.next = l1 or l2

    return head.next


class Node:
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None
```

So for such two lists:

```
[1,2,4]
[3,4,5]
```

The merged result is:
`[1,2,3,4,4,5]` when calling the function above.

What I don't understand about the code are these two lines:

```
sort_list.next = l1
sort_list = sort_list.next
```

For the first line, the 'head' get updated every time 'sort_list' is updated. For the second line, 'head' isn't affected, when sort_list is updated. Why 'head' isn't changed accordingly in the second case? In both cases, 'head' is reference of 'sort_list', so it should always change with 'sort_list'. Isn't right?

Comment: The only reason to have `head` is to return the first node of the resulting linked list (`return head.next`).  Is this your code, or are you trying to understand someone else's?

Comment: It's somebody else code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last paragraph, your initial statement is incorrect.  `head` and `sort_list` begin as references to the `0` node object.  Thereafter, `head` remains pointed to that node, while `sort_list` walks down the merged list.

```
sort_list = sort_list.next
```

is the increment statement, moving `sort_list` to the node just added to the list.  `sort_list` keeps moving to each added node, so it stays at the end of the merged list.

At the bottom, the function returns `head.next`, which is the top node of the merged list.

Try adding some simple `print` statements to trace the execution:

```
def merge(l1, l2):
    head = sort_list = Node(0)
    while l1 and l2:
        print("\nhead", id(head), head.value)
        if l1.value < l2.value:
            sort_list.next = l1
            l1 = l1.next
            sort_list = sort_list.next
            print("sort_list l1", id(sort_list),
                  sort_list.value if sort_list else None,
                  l1.value if l1 else None)

        elif l1.value >= l2.value:
            sort_list.next = l2
            l2 = l2.next
            sort_list = sort_list.next
            print("sort_list l2", id(sort_list), 
                  sort_list.value if sort_list else None,
                  l2.value if l2 else None)
```

Output:

```
head 140689225387368 0
sort_list l1 140689225387144 1 2

head 140689225387368 0
sort_list l1 140689225387088 2 4

head 140689225387368 0
sort_list l2 140689225387312 3 4

head 140689225387368 0
sort_list l2 140689225387256 4 5

head 140689225387368 0
sort_list l1 140689225386976 4 None
```

See?  `head` stays put, while `sort_list` moves along the building merge.

Comment: ， one more question, what about 'sort_list.next = l1 or l2'? It means sort_list_next will be either l1 or l2, if any is a None value? What about if both are None?

Comment: Why are you asking *me*?  You have on-line documentation available, not to mention the ultimate authority right in front of you: a computer with interactive Python.  What is the result of that expression?

Answer (score 2):

You want to keep track of the `nodes` you are adding, and also where you are in each linked list. so `l1 = l1.next` makes it so you don't add the same data point twice. `sort_list = sort_list.next` moves you to the tail of the  `sort_list` linked list, so that you are adding values to the end of the list.